# Cannot install Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with 2.5GB RAM and 120GB HDD.
I have windows 7 and Ubuntu installed side by side.

I have another 30GB space where I want to install Fedora 18 but when I try to install it, I get the following error

```
/dev/root not found
```

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this.

I get the error as soon as I click to install it.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install? From a DVD? What steps are you following?

Comment: Hi i am using a usb to install and after i boot from a usb i get a screen with 3 options ie; install fedora and try this media & install fedora and then troubleshooting with the middle option selected when i click on install fedora i get the above error

Answer (score 0):

it's not too that different from installing Ubuntu:

- pick the device/disk on which you want it to be installed
- after the partitions get populated choose a partition and select it as your `/` "root" partition.

Comment: Hi i am using a usb to install and after i boot from a usb i get a screen with 3 options ie; install fedora and try this media & install fedora and then troubleshooting with the middle option selected when i click on install fedora i get the above error

Comment: that's an issue with the way you have the USB media configured. The bootloader never gets to a graphical state after you select "install fedora" from the grub menu? How did you create the USB media? What program did you use to create it & make it bootable, if any? Were you running Windows, Ubuntu,...when you created it? You could also post the kernel parameters here: when you get to the menu, instead of pressing "Enter" to start loading the installation script, press "e" (letter E) on your keyboard; that will let you read the bootloader options.

Comment: i used universal usb installer to make it bootable...

Comment: I'm not gonna be able to narrow it down without some specific information, therefore, what I would suggest is to:

----

* reformat the pendrive

* check the ISO file that you have downloaded to make sure it's not corrupt--i.e. compare the hash signature with the signature on the website where you got it from.

* In some cases certain pendrives are not "compatible" with LiveUSB boot options--you might want to try switching to a different flashdrive/pendrive if you have one laying around.